# Delayed Jobs always instantly executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, background-process, delayed-job

I have a rails app in which I would like to use the delayed_jobs gem to send texts/emails in background processes at certain times of the day. This is how I have the relevant parts of my app set up right now:

```
 class SomeClass

   after_create :send_reminder

   def when_to_run
     self.date_time - 1.hour
   end

   def send_reminder
     MessageHandler.new().send_message
   end

   handle_asynchronously :send_reminder, run_at: Proc.new { |i| i.when_to_run }, queue: "Messages"

 end
```

The MessageHandler class is a separate class I've defined which actually houses the methods for sending texts (with Twilio) and emails (with Mailgun).

After starting delayed_job (bin/delayed_job start) and creating an instance of SomeClass, the delayed_job log reads as follows:

```
 Job SomeClass#send_reminder_without_delay (id=686) RUNNING
```

I'm not sure why it is running send_reminder_without_delay, and it's doing it every time. I've tried using `MessageHandler.new().delay.send_message` in the `send_reminder` method instead of `MessageHandler.new().send_message`, but that hasn't gotten me anywhere either.

I've searched high and low for answers and keep coming up short - any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in `run_at: Proc.new { |i| i.when_to_run }`.

I'm not entirely sure what the date_time method does but have you checked whether it actually returns time that is more than 1 hour in the future?

Otherwise the run_At will receive a time in the past and run the method.

if the return value of date_time is similar to this:

```
    def when_to_run
     Time.now - 1.hour
    end
```

Then the queue will run as soon as you start delayed job.

Check if it your run_at time is in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We were using Rails 4.2 and set the queue adapter. We needed to use this line in our config:

`config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job`